# Dynamic Programming Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have the following question on a homework
[image]

I have no idea how to solve part B (at least with a dynamic programming algorithm) because from what I can tell, the best cost for N days has nothing to do with the best cost for N-1 days.  I'm not looking for someone to do my homework for me (I know that's frowned upon here), but just for some guidance on where to start, or what subproblems to split this up into.  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post text as an image.

Answer (score 0):

(*I like you being humble so I am trying to give some hints here...Also please try to use plain text, in your own words to simplified the problem if you can, next time :)  Welcome to the community.*)

The question statement of part b already gives you a great hints: use a 2D array to store the state. It is because it's not enough to know week **i-1**'s optimal solution (which is greedy and you should have answered it at part a), meaning we have to know **something else** other than week number, which is the second dimension.

So let's start to think what is possibly the two dimension means, what do they represent and how to use them to find our optimal answer. Here I introduce my own thinking process on DP problems, it is pretty much fill-in the blanks game.

---

### Thinking Process

Intuitively, one dimension must be the week **i**, so that it may depends on some previous weeks **i-1, i-2...etc**

So let **D(i, ?)** be the 2D state, it represents the minimum cost we have to pay until week **i**.

It is saying **D(i,?) = Minimum cost till week i, with xxx being yyy**

What is **xxx, yyy**? How about **company X and Current Company Used**? Let's fit it in to see if it make sense (It is really my thinking process, with a lot trial & error to see which one seems right, by **experience**)

> D(i, X) := Minimum cost till week i, with company X being current company used

---

### More Serious Logical Thinking (TL;DR)

Seems good, no?

So we have a 2D state D(i, X), which can be represent by a 2D array D[52][3].

> **Now we have changed the problem itself**
>
> From What is the min cost till week i?
>
> To What is the min cost till week i using company X as the last
>   company used?

For Simplicity, I will just use D(i, A),  D(i, B) and D(i, C) as notation in the following.

If we already know week **i-1**'s optimal solution **using a specific company**, then we can compute current week **i**'s optimal solution.

This is because it considers all cases, mutual exclusively. By all cases, I mean no matter which week is it, you have to use one of these 3 companies after all.

And it has so-called **[optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure)** property: To calculate D(i, A) for example, the best path from D(i-1, A), D(i-1, B), D(i-1, C) including penalty if needed, must give the optimal solution of D(i, A).  Because if there is some path to week **i-1** which is not optimal (no matter which company), I can always choose another path which is optimal, and use that to calculate D(i, A) which must be better.

Note that if we do not take the second dimension **current company** into account, the original problem would not have this property and thus cannot be solved by greedy directly.

With another property called [**overlapping subproblems**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems), now our new problem can be solved by Dynamic Programming.

And when we solve the new problem, we can use the solution of our new problem to solve our original problem:  **Ans = Max(D(52, A), D(52, B), D(52, C))**

---

### Back to Homework

Okay, so here I give you some more fill-in the blanks game which may aid you to finish the problem.

1. Define D(i,X) as ____________________
2. The base case D(0, X) is ____________
3. The answer is Max(____,  ____,  ____)
4. D(i, A) = min(_____, _____, _____) + a[i] where a[i] is _________
5. D(i, B) = min(_____, _____, _____) + b[i] where b[i] is _________
6. D(i, C) = min(_____, _____, _____) + c[i] where c[i] is _________

Fill in all of these and you are good.